# Split sentence into words only using while loop

Tags: ruby

In C++, I can add a null character in the end to differentiate between words. But I do not how to in Ruby
I do not want to use splice method. Here is how I am proceeding forward with.

```
i = 0
    split_array = []
    while (i<sentence.length)
        puts (sentence.length)
        if (i+1 == " ")
```

Comment: Do you have to use a `while`? There is a much easier way: `words = sentence.split(/\W+/)` will do the whole thing (with some caveats you have to be aware of)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to. Basically in C++, I can add a null character in the end to differentiate between words. But I do not how to in Ruby

Comment: In the end of what? Why do you need to differentiate between words? the `words` array in my example has a word at each index

Comment: What `splice` method? Do you mean `split`? Why not? If you're talking about `split`, it's the fastest and the common method to break a string into chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (disregarding punctuation and case):

```
sentence = "the quick brown dog\njumped   over the lazy fox"

start_ndx = sentence.index(/\w/)
return [] if start_ndx.nil?
words = []
while start_ndx
  end_ndx = sentence.index(/\w\b/, start_ndx)
  words << sentence[start_ndx..end_ndx]
  start_ndx = sentence.index(/\w/, end_ndx+1)
end
words
  #=> ["the", "quick", "brown", "dog", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "fox"]
```